# This is a first ... - can I use the indefinite article?

Tags: grammar, articles, indefinite-article

I know with words determining somehow the order of things I should use the definite article. But I would say it depends on the context. Is the following correct?

> This is a first discussion out of many that I am planning.

Could this be right when the audience did not know I was planning these discussions?

If not, why the following is fine:

> ...if you are buying **a** first car.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to say this would be:

> This is **the** first discussion out of many I am planning.

It really doesn't matter if the audience already knows you were planning the discussions or not. We typically use *the* instead of *a(n)* where there is only one of something, and, when something is "first", there is only one of it.

If there is more than one, however, we would use an indefinite article, like this:

> This is an early discussion out of many I am planning.

(This could be referring to the first meeting, or the second or third.)

But, when there is only one, we go back to the definite article:

> This is the earliest discussion out of many I am planning.

As for phrases like:

> If you are buying a first car...

that works because we are using the phrase [a first car] to mean the first car that one particular person will purchase. Because the article would be read my many people, though, there really isn't one and only one first car. Your first car is not the same first car as my first car.

Note that, while *a first car* can be found, the [number of occurrences](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20first%20car%2Cthe%20first%20car&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) is dwarfed by the phrase *the first car*.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thinking about this, what about "a following", in an example like this: Please add a following topic to the list. I guess there should be "the following", because you mean the particular one mentioned below that, is that correct?

Comment: @JohnV - I can see how this would be maddening for the learner. I would say: _Please add **a** new topic to the list_, but it would always be, _Please add **the** following topic to the list_.

Answer (score -3):

Remove "out" and it's fine:

> This is the first discussion of many that I am planning.

Comment: You've missed the point of the question. The OP was not asking for an improved version, the OP was asking if the indefinite article could be used. You've changed it to the definite article, so, I suppose the original wasn't "fine" after all.

Comment: No I didn't. Re-read the question: "Is the following correct?" Do you really think I need to add "no?"

Comment: Sure, but the title reads: _This is **a** first … - can I use the indefinite article?_ Moreover, before asking, "Is the following correct?" the OP asks, _"I know ... I should use the definite article..."_ Lastly, pure proofreading (e.g., "Are there any mistakes?" or "Is this correct?") is expressly off-topic on ELL [unless a source of concern is clearly specified](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Any answer to this question should address the article issue with more than a rephrasing of the original sentence.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused. So can I say "This is a first" or do I need to use "the" - This is "THE" first... Context being that the audience does not know about any planned discussions, which is why I think the indefinite article is fine.